# Using a Plotly Rangeselector button without time series data

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

The Plotly docs have [this](https://plotly.com/python/range-slider/) example. They create buttons that select a date range 1m 6m and 1 year back in time when clicked. How can I use these same buttons in a Plotly with data that is not using dates as an index but numbers.

Example code using the rangeselector buttons:

```
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=6,
                     label="6m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="YTD",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="todate"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1y",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(step="all")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date"
    )
)
```

Comment: yes,  you can use whatever you like so long as it is consistent with the rest of the code.